# Error when adding a Thymeleaf layout to my Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm trying to add a header to all the pages of my Spring Boot application, so I want to use Thymeleaf to add this layout.

But when I'm trying to access my home page for exemple, I get this error message :

`Error resolving template [accueil], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

I looked through internet and found some advices to fix this issue, but none of them worked...

My layout path is : `src/main/resources/templates/layout.html` so I tried to add these prefix and suffix to my `application.properties` file :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

But it don't works...

Here are my layout.html file, my home controller and my pom.xml file :

layout.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Enums in Thymeleaf</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hello from layout</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

AccueilControleur :

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class AccueilControleur {
    @GetMapping("")
    public String index(){
        return "accueil";
    }
}
```

pom.xml dependencies :

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Pour Spring Boot, ajoutez ceci dans la section <dependencies> de votre pom.xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Did someone have an idea on that issue ?

Best regards

Comment: it's looking for a template named accueil, so change the template name to `accueil.html`